# codenameone theme.res error

Tags: lwuit, codenameone

I've a problem to deploy Codenameone application in some some devices like Samsung.

I tried to create application in manual mode without have an "theme.res" file. I added a form manually and ran it in Samsung device that hasn't OS (just support MIDP 2.0) and it ran successfully.

I tried to add some forms to "theme.res" file and work with it (you know, it's so simple to work with it). So after that I ran it in Samsung device and I got error.

What's the different between them?

Why can't it run with "theme.res" file? What's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [run codenameone j2me application on samsung devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285679/run-codenameone-j2me-application-on-samsung-devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some devices can't run the application in which designed by codenameone or lwuit. You should hard coding all of your design either with codenameone or lwuit theme.

Or you can choose manual template on codenameone wizard to develop your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do Display.init(this) before getting resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading with the correct path from the src file of your project "/resource.es"